# Adding a unique key to the oracle database table

Tags: oracle

Trying to implement a friendship table ..

To explain wat i have done till now

my DDL

```
<!-- WORKING -- "relationship" - This table used to store the relationship between users -->
create table relationship(
    relation_id number(8),
    FromUserName varchar2(30),
    ToUserName varchar2(30),
    StatusId number,
    SentTime timestamp,
    constraint relationship_pk primary key(relation_id),
    foreign key (FromUserName) references users(username),
    foreign key (ToUserName) references users(username)
);

<!--WORKING add the unique key to 'relationship' table so that a user can send request at time to user only oncle -->

ALTER TABLE relationship
ADD CONSTRAINT relation_unique UNIQUE (FromUserName, ToUserName);
```

Here is an image to explain the problem

[image]

My problem 
 have a look at last two rows . .. the users kamlesh1 send request to jitu1 and again jitu1 sends request to kamlesh1 and when i kamlesh1 accepts the request the statusid changes to 1 similar case for kamlesh to jitu when jitu accepts the request. 
I want to prevent this kind of duplication i.e 
once a user has sent u a request u cannot sent a request to him just accept his request or reject it. 
I just could'nt think of proper question title ...if u could help with that too.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You could create a unique function-based index for this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX relation_unique ON relationship ( LEAST(FromUserName, ToUserName), GREATEST(FromUserName, ToUserName) );
```

A couple of side notes: You don't need a `NUMBER` (38 digits of precision) to store a value that is either 0 or 1. `NUMBER(1)` should suffice. Also, you probably don't need the granularity of `TIMESTAMP` for `SentTime` - a `DATE` should do the trick, and might make arithmetic a bit easier (`DATE` arithmetic is expressed in days, `TIMESTAMP` arithmetic in intervals). Last, using CamelCase for column names in Oracle isn't a good idea since Oracle object names aren't case-sensitive unless you enclose them in double quotes. If you were to inspect the data dictionary you would see your columns like this: `FROMUSERNAME`, `TOUSERNAME`. Much better to use column names like `FROM_USERNAME` and `TO_USERNAME` (or `USERNAME_FROM` and `USERNAME_TO`).

Comment: Thanks sir, could u plz exaplain wat these function means ...is this wat a index is ? I m a learner .

Comment: I get these error .. cannot CREATE UNIQUE INDEX; duplicate keys found

Comment: Right, you have to remove the duplicates before you can create the index

Answer (score 0):

You should order the persons. Say, add

```
alter table relationship
  add constraint relation_order_chk
  check (fromusername < tousername);
```

Then, when inserting, do something like

```
create or replace procedure AddRelationship(p_from varchar2, p_to varchar2 ...) is
begin
  insert into relationship (fromusername, tousername, ...)
    values(least(p_from, p_to), greatest(p_from, p_to), ...);
end;
```

Comment: sir can u plz elaborate

Comment: sorry , I dont understand plz could u elaborate